How to create a new date by using one's date part and other's time part?
I have 2 dates in ISO string format. I mean 2024-07-25T00:58:00.000Z and 2024-07-30T13:35:00.000Z. I am trying to make them combine as 2024-07-25T13:35:00.000Z. Is there a way to do this with a simple solution?

What is the rule of combination?

@Jacky As I stated on header, taking one's date and other's time part

You can split date and time with .split('T'). You can concatenate strings with +.

@jabaa Thanks, my brain stopped, I think this is the simples solution

You can split date and time with .split('T') and you can concatenate strings with +.


const date1 = '2024-07-25T00:58:00.000Z';
const date2 = '2024-07-30T13:35:00.000Z';

function combineDates(date1, date2) {
  return date1.split('T')[0] + 'T' + date2.split('T')[1];
}

console.log(combineDates(date1, date2));

const expectedDate = '2024-07-25T13:35:00.000Z';
console.log(combineDates(date1, date2) === expectedDate);




I don't see a clear scenario of doing this. However, just simply pick the value directly from any defined Date value:
const date1 = "2024-07-25T00:58:00.000Z";
const date2 = "2024-07-30T13:35:00.000Z";

const dt1 = new Date(date1);
const dt2 = new Date(date2);

// This should be combination value DateTime
const combinedDate = new Date(
  Date.UTC(
    dt1.getUTCFullYear(),
    dt1.getUTCMonth(),
    dt1.getUTCDate(),
    dt2.getUTCHours(),
    dt2.getUTCMinutes(),
    dt2.getUTCSeconds(),
    dt2.getUTCMilliseconds()
  )
);

// Format the combined date back to ISO string
const combinedIsoString = combinedDate.toISOString();

console.log(combinedIsoString);


some date pickers take date and time separately, the scenario is because of this. Thx for your answer, but as jabaa's comment, I think it is more simpler, if it is an healthy solution

@JeremyFc For fast performance, indeed jabaa's solution should be faster since he/she is only using string modification.
However, if you consider about robustness and clarity, my method is more readable and handles edge cases better (e.g., time zone differences).
However, like a said, depend on the scenario :) Cheer :)

Thx brother for the clarification, I am now testing it :)
